# Passing peripheral between View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, parameter-passing

I've been stuck on how to pass a BLE peripheral (or any object) between my two story boards. 
There are two views. In the second view, I can for peripherals and store them in a table and when I click on the one I need I will navigate back to the first story board where I will send a data packet. So I need to pass the peripheral from the second to the first storyboard. 
I've tried implementing a delegate and passing a pointer across to the second story board. So far I can store the peripheral in this variable but as soon as I try to navigate back to the main view it is gone.
This is my code for setting the passed pointer as the peripheral and popping back to the main view (connected_peripheral is the peripheral I've selected from the table and Selected_peripheral is the variable from the other view:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{

NSLog(@"%@, Peripheral Connected",Connected_Peripheral);

//Method for passing data- store in variable and pop the view back to main screen


ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
viewController.selectedPeripheral = Connected_Peripheral;

viewController.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"Captured data: %@", viewController.selectedPeripheral);

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];




// Stop scanning
 [TableViewController.centralManager stopScan];
NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");

// Clear the data that we may already have
[self.data setLength:0];

// Make sure we get the discovery callbacks
 peripheral.delegate = self;

// Search only for services that match our UUID
[peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
```

}

and here is how I've defined the delegate method : 
`

```
//Delegate for passing data
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)dataFromController:(CBPeripheral *)selectedPeripheral;

@end
@interface ViewController : UIViewController < CBPeripheralDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral   *selectedPeripheral;//store peripheral



@end
```

Comment: You aren't assigning the delegate properly.  You need the calling first view controller to set itself as the delegate of the second view controller and implement `dataFromController:`  You will then call `self.delegate dataFromController:connectedPeripheral` (`Connected_Peripheral` doesn't comply with variable naming conventions - variables should start with a lowercase and use camelCase - an uppercase letter for subsequent new words)

Comment: U also can use unwind segue to return the value also if the delegate is too culprit though, its same like forward segue and easy to implement